# Anime about a group that was searching for a powerful artifact

Tags: story-identification, anime, mecha

A group was searching for a powerful artifact that granted power(?). Some people are born with animal features. They stumbled upon a pub and decided to grab something to eat and they noticed that there is someone that doesn't have features but is wearing a headband that had animal ears on it.

They out him and he goes with them to find said artifact which I think was like a powerful egg that had to be activated somehow. Towards the end of the anime you find out that it's actually him that is the powerful artifact but he erased his own memories the last time he was activated. When he was remembering he noticed that his hair was actually red not the blond/brown he thought it was.

I saw this between 2006 and 2013 and I was watching it online I believe.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you see this?  Do you recall the names of any of the characters or places?

Comment: i saw this between 2006 and 2013 and honestly what i wrote is all i can remember about it and i was watching it online i believe

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: You tagged this with mecha, but didn't mention this in the question. It might be helpful to describe something about their design (or if you cant maybe look at a couple that have destinct designs, ex. gundam/power rangers/voltron/gen lock, and see which look most similar to what you recall)